# Search Results based on a string in the URL

Tags: search-results, result-source

In SharePoint 2013 search results, I would like to configure the search results webparts such that if any query is typed in the search box, the results should display once if the url has a string for ex."article" in it.

I would like to check the urls which are returned from the search and if it has a specific string in the url, I want to display those results alone in the search results.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Search query]

You can change search query in search result -> edit webpart -> Change query

select property filter as path , select contains option and then select manual option and enter the manual value there.

Comment: i tried it.. Its returning no results.